# How to get all files from archive folder? SharpCompress

Tags: c#, zip, sharpcompress

I have directory named "data" in zip archive, in this directory I have other directories
I need to get all directories from data and iterate through them and then get all files from this directories.
How can I do this?

Comment: Give a look at the [path class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-6.0)  and at the [directory class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-6.0) these contains the main method to use for your necessities, the main one being `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` probably

Comment: I can get directory but how to get all directories in this directory from archive?

Comment: give a look at the documentation and find out, I don't have time right now to make a code sample, but I'm sure you can find it on the docu